# Genymotion 2.7.2 not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, genymotion

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 x64. Previous version of genymotion was working perfectly. After i updated till 2.7.2, when i launch a virtual machine all the OS freezez and can move only my mouse :(

Any1 met similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before.
Go to "Software and Updates" > "Additional Drivers", and change to the proprietary driver for your card. Reboot.